# Hibernate Joins In Spring boot application

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring boot MVC application with hibernate ORM.

I have a table as student which has foreign keys from other tables.

**Student.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")

public class student{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long STUDENT_ID;   

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")
private Long COURSE_ID;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ACDYEAR_ID")
private Long ACDYEAR_ID; 

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SEMESTER_ID")
private Long SEMESTER_ID;
}
```

**StudentRepository:**

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN ACADEMICSYEAR ON      STUDENT.ACDYEAR_ID = ACADEMICSYEAR.ACDYEAR_ID  INNER JOIN ACADEMICSCOURSE ON STUDENT.COURSE_ID = ACADEMICSCOURSE.COURSE_ID where STUDENT_ID=?1",
        nativeQuery=true)
 public STUDENT findOneID(Long id);
```

Same query in sql server returns populated academic year table and course table but here it is giving an error like

```
   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.boot.model.STUDENT.COURSE_ID references an unknown entity: java.lang.Long
```

Comment: JPA thinks that `Long` is the name of the linked entity. You must use the class name of the linked entity. For example, if `COURSE_ID` links to the `COURSE` table, you would have `private COURSE course_id`. However, you annotation would mean that there is a one-to-one relationship, which doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 2):

## Hey there,

The reason it does not work its because you are trying to map `Long` object as `entity` ( because of `OneToOne,ManyToOne` mapping). you should map each field to another entity instead of mapping it to Long. Or, just fetch the ids

### Two solutions:

## First option - fetch ids only

remove all `@OneToOne` annotation and `JoinColumn`

```
@Column(name="COURSE_ID")
private Long COURSE_ID;

@Column(name="ACDYEAR_ID")
private Long ACDYEAR_ID; 


@Column(name = "SEMESTER_ID")
private Long SEMESTER_ID;
```

## Second option

Create an entity for each table i.e `Course entity`, `Semester entity` and ACADEMICSYEAR  entity`and change the`Long `in each place to be that entity`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having type of the id of the entity in the association, have the type of the entity. Example

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")

public class student{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long STUDENT_ID;   

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")
private Course course;
}
```

Where `Course` is the associated entity in the unidirectional relationship